# Custom live distro - ways to detect it is running inside virtual machine (or prevent running in VM altogether)

Tags: livecd, virtualization

I am creating a custom live distro that will be a specialist work environment for those of my employees that are on the road.

I am looking for ways to detect or, ideally, prevent my live distro from being run inside a virtual machine (I am only worried about Windows desktop virtualization like VMWare, VirtualBox; I'm not bothered about KVM/Xen).

Are there reasonably easy mechanisms to either cripple my live distro (e.g. by removing kernel drivers) so it does not run at all within a VM, or at least be able to detect it?

If there are, what are the potential pitfalls? The users won't be overly technical so I just need to make it hard enough to circumvent detection/reporting/running inside VM.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The VM's report them self's to the OS as VM in CPU info and other hardware info. What ever you do after you have that info is up to you. 'uname -a' should say VMware or other.

Comment: @SethHikari This depends on the VM. VirtualBox OSE (which is currently the most popular among free VMs) will not advertise anything at that level - you'd have to search deeper.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to prevent it from running in a VM?

Comment: And out of curiosity - what is better about XEN/KVM than VirtualBox, Hyper-V or VMWare?

Comment: Kevin, it's important for me to force my team to work from read-only media (the reasons for that are complicated but are mostly to do with semi-repressive nature of political regime in the country where we work for opposition parties). Most users are not tech-savvy and get only basic data security training. The live CD is meant to contain all the tools necessary for work but can be inconvenient for someone who wants to run all their usual 'fun' applications/games and because reboots wipe out changes. Therefore I want to remove the temptation of setting up VM (with shared folders capability)

Comment: Nils, it's not about better, it's just that someone running KVM/Xen is quite likely to be tech-savvy and be capable of understanding data security issues. Having said that, I'd still rather they didn't do it and worked straight up from read-only media

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you will have to do many tests to create a fairly universal tester script. Here are things you might look at:

- The output of `lspci -v` might contain VM name, especially in `VGA` description.
- `dmidecode` output might be the hardest thing for a VM to fake (simulate a "real" hardware) - look for similar things as in `lspci`.

Comment: You're answer made me google: There's [`imvirt`](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html), a Perl script; [`virt-what`](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) looks good, too; and [quite some discussion on this on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application).

Comment: Wow, a very interesting method [there on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application/154222#154222). Too bad it is not 100% accurate (as the comments indicate).

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you guys once again - the answers and links you provided have been very helpful for me to achieve what I've set out to.

Comment: @sr_ I take back my initial enthusiasm; in today's multi-core environments, this code is pretty useless.

Comment: @knef If the answer was helpful to you, consider indicating that by *upvoting* or *accepting* it.